# Hooking event at runtime accross different project in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, eventhandler

I have two Different project , ProjectA and ProjectB, Inside a Solution.
Project B Contains a form having a  button for which click event is hooked at some class of ProjectA,

To set this event I have a handler inside form of project B as

```
 public event EventHandler ProjectBFormButtonClick
        {
            add { btnEncounterClick.Click += value; }
            remove { btnEncounterClick.Click -= value; }
        }
```

and in Project A I have the method to handle above method.
Inside project A i am setting above as

```
 ProjectBForm1.ProjectBFormButtonClick+= ProjectAFormButtonHandle;
```

Now I wan't to pass some event args from form of project B to Project A, is it possible?

Comment: Create a class that inherits from EventArgs and then pass an instance of your class when calling the event see (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You have to attach an internal Click event handler in ProjectB then relay that event with you parameter to the ProjectA Handler.

Comment: How can attaching an internal event rellay to some external handler... can u explain this